# Customize Checkout Page And Remove Postal Code And Extra Fields

Tags: magento2, checkout, orders, customize

Hello Friends I Want to Customize My Checkout Page In Magento 2 and remove extra fields `Zip/Postal` `Country` Etc. I Using Magento 2.2.6 Version And My Theme Is **Fastest**.

I alsoedited `checkout_index_index.xml` File

Here's the codes

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">MilkJarCookies_OrderDeliveryDate/js/view/shipping</item>
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="shipping-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="country_id" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">1001</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                <item name="region_id" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">1002</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                <item name="region" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">1002</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                <item name="postcode" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
```

Comment: after above change, do you run caching and deploy command and then check?

Comment: Yes I Run Cache Clean And Deploy Command From SSH Access.

Answer (score 3):

Try following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="shipping-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="custom_new_field" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract</item>
                                                                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">1105</item>
                                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="tooltip" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="description" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom New Field</item>
                                                                        </item>
                                                                        <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/input</item>
                                                                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                                                                        <item name="customScope" xsi:type="string">shippingAddress.custom_new_field</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">shippingAddress.custom_attributes.custom_new_field</item>
                                                                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom New Field</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                <item name="postcode" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Thanks Your Help But This Not Works For Me.

Comment: @Abdullah this is tested code. Should work.

Comment: Dear I Using magento 2.2.6 version can you tell me where thi checkout_index_index.xml File Location Because That file i found there this codes not working even i delete this file but noting happen on checkout page. Please Help Or Suggest Me Any Free Extension For Fix This Issue 
Advance Thanks